# Vlookup among different workbook and sheets and update value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two different workbooks. One is the master file and the other workbook is Workbook2 which has different worksheets. I need to look into the master file into column A, column E and column F. If the value from Column A and Column F is found in any of the sheets  in Workbook2 then the last column in the sheets will be populated with column E from the master file. Column A and Column F from the master file is found in Column B and Column C in Workbook2. Any help is highly appreciated!!

```
    MasterFile

            A     B      C     D           E            F        
        Yahoo    009    899   777   Spoke to client    INV# 123      


    WorkBook2 --Expected Results Column Q

    SHEET1


         A       B         C         D       E       F       Q
          ID123   Google   INV# 345    89      XX     333   

    SHEET2 --The result was found therefore column Q is populated with Column E from
 the master file. 

         A          B          C     D         E      F      Q
        ID009     Yahoo   INV#123   777      444      223    **Spoke to client**


    SHEET3

        A             B            C          D         E      F    Q
       ID456       MICROSOFT     INV#000      676      989    123
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to use excel as a database, which IMHO is not a good idea. Although one solution might be [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-multiple-critiera). But even then it will not work, because the data in the MasterFile is incompatible with the data in SHEET2: `INV# 123` is not equal to `INV#123`. So it will never give a result.

If you manage to get correct data, then try this:

1. Insert an extra column at the beginning of the MasterFile and populate it with (the original columns A and F have now shifted to B and G)

   =B1&G1
2. Now add a VLOOKUP formula in SHEET2

   =VLOOKUP(B1&C1,[Masterfile.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$G,6,FALSE)

Another option might be put the masterfile in a database table and use a SQL query to get the data. Something like:

```
SELECT m.E FROM MasterFile m WHERE SHEET2.B = m.A AND SHEET2.C = m.F
```

There might be some errors in the SQL syntax, but I hope you get the idea.